# Apache: How to Use Modules?

Tags: apache-2.2

As I see in the `httpd.conf` file some codes needs these wrappers `Directory`, `IfModule`, `Files`, `IfDefine`, `Location`.. and some nothing. But I don't really understand what should I use where and why?

For example:

As I've seen some wrappers can have attributes like this, which should refer to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` folder only :

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
    Options All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Unlike this:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This wrapper without an attribute maybe refers to all directories.

But would be good to know exactly how can I manage these modules, because it's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't any substitute for being aware of the manual when starting out. The directives you describe above are all part of [**Apache Core**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html).

`<Directory ...> </Directory>` blocks apply to the named filesystem directory and it's sub directories. Your `<Directory />` statement above does in fact have an attribute - `/` which means the whole filesystem. Note that there are rules regarding how different `<Directory ...>` blocks matching the same filesystem directory or part of the path interact.

`<Files ... > </Files>` the directives apply to the matched files e.g. deny access to files called config.php

```
<Files config.php>
     order allow,deny
     deny from all
</Files>
```

etc.

[Directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) 
[Files directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files)
[Location directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location)
[IfModule directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifmodule)
[IfDefine directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifdefine)

Answer (score 2):

These are called "Directives" (not wrappers) and the best place to learn about them is through the "Directive Quick Reference" (which is what everyone uses quite a bit).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

```
<Directory />
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

> This wrapper without an attribute maybe refers to all directories.

No. This (/) refers to the top level directory of the drive that Apache is running on.

The effects of this, on the other hand, do apply to all the sub-directories of that directory unless another <Directory ...> block overrides those settings.